# Wrong solution of quadratic programming in R

Tags: r, optimization, modeling

I am trying to solve quadratic programming in R with package osqp. However, the results looked so wrong.

The code for reproducing the example attached here:（the objective function is the minimization

```
library(osqp)
library(Matrix)
P <- Matrix(c(1., 0.,0,
              0., 1.,0, 0,0,1), 3, 3, sparse = TRUE)
q <- c(0, 1,1)
A <- Matrix(c(1., 1., 0.,
              1., 0., 1.,1,0,1), 3, 3, sparse = TRUE)
l <- c(1.2, 0., 0.7)
u <- c(2., 0.8, 0.7)
settings <- osqpSettings(alpha = 1.0,eps_abs = 1.0e-05, eps_rel = 1.0e-05,)
model <- osqp(P, q, A, l, u, settings)
res <- model$Solve()
```

This is the output of the model, and it shows the optimal value is 0.7

[image]

However, if use the optimal solution to plug into the objective function it gives me 1.018556

```
#this should be the final objective value after solving
0.5*t(res$x)%*%P%*%res$x+t(c(0,1,1))%*%res$x

#the solution
res$x
#0.6261887 0.3500000 0.3500000
```

More importantly, this is not the optimal solution. If I eyeballed the solution, I could find another answer with a smaller objective function with a value of 0.5,0.1,0.6
I am not sure what I did wrong.

Thank you for any advice in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to fool OQSP (in python) to give your result.

I first suspected of `alpha` but it seems to make no difference.
The other thing is the number of iterations, it could have not converged after 25 iterations, but in that case I would not expect an objective of 0.70000.

```py
import osqp
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
P = np.array([[1., 0.,0],
            [0., 1.,0], 
            [0,0,1]]).T
q = np.array([0, 1,1])[None, :];
A = np.array([[1., 1., 0.],
              [1., 0., 1.],
              [1,0,1]]).T
l = np.array([1.2, 0., 0.7])[:, None]
u = np.array([2., 0.8, 0.7])[:, None]

m = osqp.OSQP()
m.setup(P=csr_matrix(P), A=csr_matrix(A), l=l, u=u, q=q.T,
        alpha=1.0, eps_abs = 1.0e-05, eps_rel = 1.0e-05, max_iter=25)
results = m.solve()
```

This gives

```
x = [0.45492868, 0.35002252, 0.35002252]
```

Already close to the optimal solution of `[0.5, 0.35, 0.35]`. One thing that I noticed is that `q%*%x=0.7`.

Looking closer I see that the last row of your `A` is `q`, and the corresponding constraints specify that `0.7 <= x(1) + x(2) <= 0.7`. i.e. any valid solution for your problem have `q'x = 0.7` thus we conclude that `x' P x = 0` internally.

The solution you shown is very close to the one I obtain if I set `P` matrix to zero

```
m.setup(P=csr_matrix(P)*0, A=csr_matrix(A), l=l, u=u, q=q.T,
        alpha=1.0, eps_abs = 1.0e-05, eps_rel = 1.0e-05, max_iter=100)
results = m.solve()
results.x
```

```txt
-----------------------------------------------------------------
           OSQP v0.6.2  -  Operator Splitting QP Solver
              (c) Bartolomeo Stellato,  Goran Banjac
        University of Oxford  -  Stanford University 2021
-----------------------------------------------------------------
problem:  variables n = 3, constraints m = 3
          nnz(P) + nnz(A) = 9
settings: linear system solver = qdldl,
          eps_abs = 1.0e-05, eps_rel = 1.0e-05,
          eps_prim_inf = 1.0e-04, eps_dual_inf = 1.0e-04,
          rho = 1.00e-01 (adaptive),
          sigma = 1.00e-06, alpha = 1.00, max_iter = 25
          check_termination: on (interval 25),
          scaling: on, scaled_termination: off
          warm start: on, polish: off, time_limit: off

iter   objective    pri res    dua res    rho        time
   1  -9.9950e-03   1.20e+00   7.01e+01   1.00e-01   5.74e-05s
  25   7.0000e-01   2.66e-15   6.94e-18   1.00e-01   1.07e-03s

status:               solved
number of iterations: 25
optimal objective:    0.7000
run time:             1.79e-03s
optimal rho estimate: 1.70e+00

array([0.62618873, 0.35      , 0.35      ])
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I think it makes sense, but I am so confused why did the model set my P matrix to 0 even if I explicitly made it as diagonal matrix?

Comment: When I changed the P matrix in my code to a non-sparse matrix, the results would be correct! I am so curious why would the spareness of the matrix in P affect the true results.

Comment: It is certainly not a problem with the solver, notice that I am passing a [compressed row sparse matrix](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html#scipy-sparse-csr-matrix)

Comment: Thank you for accepting the answer. Were you able to have it working with sparse matrices at the end?

Comment: Not really, I converted into normal matrix and it worked. Really confused why sparse matrix will generate different results. Thank you for putting the answers together!